# Iterate through substring to find special character and remove character

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that accepts an input_list containing strings and returns an output_list containing strings based on these conditions. For each string in input_list: 
1. if the string has '$' then remove all the characters that appear after the '$' from the string for example "amazeing23$ing23" should become "amaze".
2. Add the resultant string to output_list for example "amaze"
3. if the string does not have '$' then add a string to the output_list followed by its length for example "world5"

def my_list(input_list):
    output_list = []
    #iterate through the string in the list
    for item in input_list:
        item = item.split()
        print(item)

```
    # Iterate through each character to check for $ sign.
    for char in item:
        if '-' in char:
            char = item.split() 
            char = item.remove(item[0]+1)
            output_list.append(item)
            #print(output_list)

        if '-' != char:
            char = char + str(len(char))
            output_list.append(char)
return output_list
```

input_list=["amazieng23$ing23","world", "wuond3erful$u3"]
result=my_list(input_list)
print(result)

This is the sample input:
input_list=["amazieng23$ing23","world", "wuond3erful$u3"]
Expected output:
output_list =["amaze","world5", "wonderful"]
I am able to split the list that has $ but I cannot remove characters that are after the $ sign. I am also having error "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly" when I am trying to add the length of the string after the string for step three.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you should really work on formatting. It looks like you've got things that should be code in there. Additionally the code makes no sense in terms of what you're trying to achieve I'm afraid...

Comment: Use the curly bracket button to indent and let it format as code.

Comment: Python strings are immutable. You cannot change them, least of all by extracting a character to a variable and overwriting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should be what you're looking for:

```
def my_list(input_list):
    output_list = []
    for item in input_list:
        split_string = item.split('$')
        if len(split_string) > 1:
            pre_string = split_string[0]
            for char in '$'.join(split_string[1:]):
                pre_string = pre_string.replace(char,'')
            output_list.append(pre_string)
        else:
            output_list.append(split_string[0] + str(len(split_string[0])))
    return output_list

input_list=["amazieng23$ing23","world", "wuond3erful$u3"]

output = my_list(input_list)

for i in output:
    print(i)
```

Which has the output:

```
amaze
world5
wonderfl
```

Note the `u` in wonderful is missing as it can't check if it's a real word or not and you've already wanted to remove the `u`.

NB: It takes the entire string after the first $ to remove characters. E.g. `Anacbborndla$r$b$rl` would return `Anaconda`

Answer (score 1):

Python strings are immutable. You shouldn't be changing certain index values of strings as you are trying to do. You can do much better than this.

The idea is that you iterate your input_list one-by-one, try finding "$" in your string using `string.find("$")`, the function will return either the index where "$" is present or -1 in case "$" is not present in the string. Based on this check, you do the required manipulation to string and add that string to the `output_list`.

```
def do_string_manipulation(input_list):
    output_list = []
    for element in input_list:
        index = element.find("$")

        # do condition manipulation here
        if index != -1:
            element = element[:index]
        else:
            element = element + "".join(map(str, range(1, len(element)+1)))

        output_list.append(element)
    return output_list

print(do_string_manipulation(["amaze$123", "amaze"]))
```

This results in

```
['amaze', 'amaze12345']
```

A nasty one liner code to do that

```
output_list = [element[:element.find("$")] if (element.find("$") != -1) else element+"".join(map(str, range(1, len(element)+1))) for element in input_list]
```